# Route is working from Postman, but it is not working from client

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am trying to fix a 400: Bad Request error. I get a 200 success when I make a PUT request from Postman [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pQwN.png) . However, when I try the route from the browser, it gives me that 400.

> angular.js:11881 PUT
>   http://localhost:8000/api/users/addStock/578430b65bd7a5dca37bf2e5 400
>   (Bad Request)
>
> err:  Object {data: Object, status: 400, config: Object, statusText:
>   "Bad Request"}

stock.html

```
<form ng-submit='addStock()'>
    <input type="text" ng-model='addObj.symbol' placeholder="symbol" required>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
</form>
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('stockCtrl', function($scope,User){
    $scope.addStock = () => {
        let userId = '578430b65bd7a5dca37bf2e5';
        User.addStock(userId, $scope.addObj.symbol)
          .then(res => {
            console.log("res.data: ", res.data);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("err: ", err);
          })
    }
```

service.js

```
app.service('User', function($http) {
    this.addStock = (id, symbol) => {
      return $http.put(`/api/users/addStock/${id}`, symbol);
    }
}
```

routes/api/users.js

```
router.put('/addStock/:userId',(req,res)=>{

  User.findById(req.params.userId, (err, user)=>{
    if(err || !user) return res.status(400).send(err || {error: 'user not found'});

    let stock = {
      symbol : req.body.symbol
    }
    user.stocks.push(stock);
    user.save((err, savedStock)=>{
      res.status(err ? 400 : 200).send(err || savedStock);
    })
  })
})
```

If anybody can help me. I will be very greatful. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there any logging on the server side?
What is in `response.data`?

Comment: Can you show us the request sent from Postman including headers?

Comment: @jchen86 In the res.data  shows the body sent with the request and the 400 codes. [see image](http://i.imgur.com/swvAdbh.png)

Comment: @Keerthivasan This is the link of the 200 from the Postman. [see image](http://i.imgur.com/crxTLpy.png)

Comment: `symbol` is just a string. It looks like you should be using `{symbol: symbol}` in the `$http` call

Comment: Angular also sends data as `application/json` whereas your Postman example seems to be submitting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. To handle either, you'll need to have `app.use(bodyParser.json());` if you don't already. See http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body

Comment: Get the cURL from Postman and also from the browser (Chrome supports this) and compare, that might provide more insight on the issue.

Comment: @M22an I can already guess... Postman will have the request body as `symbol=a` and Angular will (probably) have `"a"`

Comment: Hmm, most likely @Phil accept type might be the issue.

Comment: @Phil Thank you. It works!  Using {symbol: symbol}

Answer (score 1):

To summarise my comments above...

`symbol` is just a string. It looks like you should be using an object with a "symbol" key in the `$http` call, ie

```
return $http.put(`/api/users/addStock/${id}`, {symbol: symbol});
```

---

Also, Angular sends data as `application/json` by default whereas your Postman example seems to be submitting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. To handle either type of request body, you'll need to have

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

if you don't already. See https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body